# Adding data to a data extension with REST API lead to a 500 error

Tags: rest-api, marketing-cloud, gack

I am trying to add data to a data extension using the Exact Target REST API.
In the following image the data extension configuration is shown:
[image: Data Extension Definition]

Using the form in https://code.exacttarget.com/api/fuel-api-family-auth and my client id and client secret, I created an access token in order follow the procedure explained on https://code.exacttarget.com/api/dataevents-row to add data to a data extension.

Every time, I am getting a 500 error as shown on the next image:
[image: 500 Internal error]

Any ideas why?

Comment: Usually HTTP 500 errors indicate problems with the server/service, not the client.

Comment: Thanks, that is the meaning of HTTP 500 : Internal Error. I am trying to find why I received this error while using an example from the help page.

Comment: Right; I just wanted to re-iterate that it might be something outside of your control, if ET is correctly using HTTP error codes. Have you contacted ET support? Did they have any suggestions?

Comment: @DarienMartinez What HTTP command are you using? POST or PUT?

Comment: @MikeChale Often times our 500 errors are just bad calls in, or not in a format it expects. They aren't ideal responses.

Comment: @KellyJAndrews: I am using a PUT as it said on the documentation. My first iteration was to use a POST because it was a new record, but the documentation said PUT.

Comment: @MikeChale: Yes, I contacted ET support. They point me out to this site to post the question.

Comment: Im doing some testing right now - I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Where can I find the API console shown in your images? It looks very useful but I don't see any mention of it on https://code.exacttarget.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I have it, and it's less than thrilling.  The `GUID` that is presented isn't the ExactTarget official `GUID`.  Each object (like data extensions), when created in our data base, is given a `GUID` and a `CustomerKey`.  The ExactTarget auto-generated `CustomerKey` is ***NOT A `GUID`***!

So you can get this to work with:

```
PUT https://www.exacttargetapis.com/hub/v1/dataevents/key:[THE CustomerKey THAT LOOKS LIKE A GUID]/rows/Email:a@a.com?access_token=...
```

Should work like a charm.

Comment: By using the key approach with the External Key, the operation worked as expected.

Comment: I never realized that the key produced was not actually the `GUID`.  That was a learning experience for me.

Comment: I am facing a similar kind of error (GUID related) while loading into a data extension.
How to find the Customer Key that looks like a GUID?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try an email address other than a@a.com - I've seen the error show when using fake or spammy email addresses that get caught by the internal email validator. Try an actual email address and see if that works.

Comment: I tried it with a real email with the same results.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will help anyone, but I had the same error for 2 days. It turns out the issue was with the json payload.

I was wrapping it in {} and this was throwing that error, and as soon as I changed it to [{}] it worked great.

Happy Hacking.

Answer (score 1):

In the Above screenshots you have Email as a key, but are sending it in as a value. This will give a 500 error as well as a errorCode 0. I ran into a similar issue when doing it and passing key instead of "keys". It returns a simple 500 error.

```
[
  {
    "Keys" : { "Email": "a@a.com" },
    "Values" : { "FirstName" : "Hello", "LastName": "LastName"}
  } 
]
```